Do Australians transiting in Istanbul airport need a visa if they have to pick up bags to transfer?
I'm an Australian inbound on an Emirates flight to Istanbul.  I've been told that to transfer to my next outbound International flight on Turkish Airlines I'll need to pick up my bags and then check them in. So, that means going through passport control . The transit time is 2 hours . My question is : do I need a full Turkey visa ? Or is there an easy transit process? Thanks for your help.

To check using eg IATA we need to know your next destination. IMHO 2 hours sounds tight, in practice it’s probably more like 1.5 hours allowing for gate closure for your onbound flight. Less say 15 minutes to deplane, 45 minutes to clear Immigration.

You need an e-Visa, but most importantly this seems awfully short. I suppose the reason you need to do that is because the two flights are booked separately (self-transfer)? If that’s the case then remember you need to have deplaned, gone through passport control, reclaimed your bags, gone to departures and checked in before the check-in deadline for your onward flight (one hour before departure). If everything goes smoothly you probably only have a few minutes to spare. If there is any delay you are on your own…

Thanks for your advice. It sounds as if transfer time needs to be more - both of you agree . And it looks like that route is simply not the best . I can transit via Dubai  or Doha .thanks for your helpful comments !
